# installation of TypeScript and Javascript in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation

I'm new to visual studio code where I want to have welcome screen like this:

[image]

But my screen is like this

[image]

How can I customize my screen where I get options to install support for JavaScript, TypeScript

if you see the first screenshot In the WELCOME screen there is

Customize - Tools and Languages - Install support for Type Script, Java Script ....

Please be kind since I'm new and in learning phase and posted this question after several google searches

Comment: I think they are the same thing for different versions of VSC, look at the icons in the Activity Bar, img 1 uses the old style of Debug icon, There is no need to install anything for JavaScript/TypeScript it is build-in

Comment: @rioV8 thanks for the advise, you are right JavaScript/TypeScript is built in VS Code

Answer (score 0):

That thing you are referring to is called the activity bar, which can be activated in several ways but the easiest way to do so would be through the Command Pallette.

To use the command pallet, you can click on View> and pick Command Pallette. A small textbox should appear at the top. Type in `> Toggle Activity Bar Visibility` , which should make your toggle bar visible again!

Through there you can go to extensions (The box looking thing)  and install support for the things you're in need of.

Comment: updated my question. 

in the welcome screen there is
Customize - Tools and Languages - Install support for Type Script, Java Script 

How can I get this

Comment: You want the _text_ to show or do you want to install support for TypeScript and JavaScript?

Comment: I want the Text "Customize - Tools and Languages - Install support for Type Script, Java Script" to be shown in the Get Started/Welcome Screen